adding rs232 ports to Asrock h470w deskmini

Hardware: AsRoCk deskmini h470w
Running: Intel core 10th gen i3-10100 CPU 3.60GHz
OS: arch
Available: usb 2.0, sata 3 (data & power), and potentially m.2 wifi slot as pci-e???  it probably doesnt apply but I have an audio and fan2 headers open as well...

I am trying to find a more affordable option to this: https://www.startech.com/en-us/cards-adapters/icusb232int2. I know it works but I would Ideally like a ps/2 and com port and not to pay 75 for a serial port if I can avoid it.
the two links are just a couple that I found but obviously they have different connections and I haven't found any documentation of an adapter or if this could be plugged into any of the other spots available on my motherboard. I could use the wifi m2 slot and add through pci-e but that looks like I need an 11th gen but I've read even more confusing reports of if that slot will work with 10th gen just with less lanes and of course asRock is not helpful from what I have read.  This was my first build and am obviously new to motherboard connection compatibility. products like the startech link above make me think it has to be possible.
https://www.ebay.com/itm/294496843456?epid=1103967974
https://www.startech.com/en-us/cables/plate9m2p16
looks like the startech is a 10 pin and the hp on ebay is a 21/22 or something pin.
is this possible to wire one of these to my board? I am not afraid to solder and make my own if that is the best option... that would be fun.
Just to get it out of the way I am not interested in a usb to rs232 cable I have one for my macbook, for my desktop I would like it wired to the board.
